# Getting interesting error when compressing the JS files - trying to read a folder as JS file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I have a Grunt task that loops through directories and sub directories and compresses the JS and CSS files.

I get the following error which means that it accidentally thought `less.js` folder is a JavaScript file. I am wondering is it possible to configure that regular expression (wildcard) to skip directories that have name such as `less.js`.

[image]

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        uglify: {
            options: {
                mangle: false
            },
            files: {
                expand: true,
                flatten: false,
                cwd: "script",
                src: ["**/*.js", "**/!*.min.js"],
                dest: "release/script",
                ext: ".js"
            }
        }, cssmin: {
            target: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    flatten: false,
                    cwd: "style",
                    src: ["**/*.css", "**/!*.min.css"],
                    dest: "release/style",
                    ext: ".css"
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-cssmin");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-uglify");

    grunt.registerTask("default", ["uglify", "cssmin"]);
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't adding `"!*.js/"` work? Thats what I would try.

Comment: `EISDIR` means that the target of the operation is a directory in reality but that the expected filetype of the target is something other than a directory. it looks like the `less.js`is a folder...

Comment: @somethinghere That is a smart solution. Thanks.

Comment: You could also use a filter. Take a look and the second example, you should be able to modify it: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#custom-filter-function

Comment: @alpha Sometimes simplicity is key :)

Comment: Just curious. Why do u want such a directory name?

Comment: @Vishwanath bower downloads the less.js library in less.js folder.

Comment: @somethinghere Please add your comment as an answer to makrk this question answered.

Comment: @Vishwanath Done so. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could decide to ignore any folder that contains `.js` in the folder name by adding this rule to your files:

```
!*.js/
```